# Introducing iterator and chunksize in pd.read_csv for test data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new in python. I read this [Kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/devilears/siraj-s-steps-lstm).

In that kernel, he used the train data with chunksize 150_000

```
train = pd.read_csv('../input/train.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=150_000, dtype={'acoustic_data': np.int16, 'time_to_failure': np.float64})
```

I visualized the X_train(statistical features) and y_train(given time_to_failure) using python. It gave me good visualizations

```
    train = pd.read_csv('../input/train.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=150_000, dtype={'acoustic_data': np.int16, 'time_to_failure': np.float64})

    X_train = pd.DataFrame()
    y_train = pd.Series()
    for df in train:
        ch = gen_features(df['acoustic_data'])
        X_train = X_train.append(ch, ignore_index=True)
        y_train = y_train.append(pd.Series(df['time_to_failure'].values[-1]))

   #Visulization function 
    plotstatfeature(X_train,y_train.to_numpy(dtype ='float32'))
```

For the test data, plotted same visualizations between X_test(statistical features) and y_hat(calculated time_to_failure) using the same function

```
submission = pd.read_csv('../input/sample_submission.csv', index_col='seg_id')
X_test = pd.DataFrame()

# prepare test data
for seg_id in submission.index:
    seg = pd.read_csv('../input/test/' + seg_id + '.csv')
    ch = gen_features(seg['acoustic_data'])
    X_test = X_test.append(ch, ignore_index=True)

X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)    
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1)
y_hat = model.predict(X_test)
submission['time_to_failure'] = y_hat
submission.to_csv('submission.csv')

#Visulization function 
plotstatfeature(X_test,y_hat.to_numpy(dtype ='float32'))
```

**Question 1:**

Is it meaningful to visualize X_test(statistical features) and y_hat(calculated time_to_failure)

**Question 2(main question):**

The visualization of test data are not good like train data .because train data is read in chunksize of 150000 giving the clear visualization while test data is full data which gives the more dense unclear visulization. **How I can convert the test data in same chunksize of 150000 for the same uniform visualization 
just as train data visulization?**

For converting the test data in the same chunksize of 150000 I tried to modify this line by introducing iterator and chunksize in the code

**First case:**

```
submission = pd.read_csv('../input/sample_submission.csv', index_col='seg_id' , iterator=True, chunksize=150_000)
```

But it gave me this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('D:/code.py', wdir='D:/')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 827, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "D:/code.py", line 299, in 
>       main()
>
> File "D:/code.py", line 239, in main
>       test(X_train, y_train)
>
> File "D:/code.py", line 168, in test
>       for seg_id in submission.index:
>
> AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'index'

**2nd case**

```
seg = pd.read_csv('test/' + seg_id + '.csv'  , iterator=True, chunksize=150000)
```

it gave me this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('D:/code.py', wdir='D:/')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 827, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "D:/code.py", line 299, in 
>       main()
>
> File "D:/code.py", line 239, in main
>       test(X_train, y_train)
>
> File "D:/code.py", line 170, in test
>       ch = gen_features(seg['acoustic_data'])
>
> TypeError: 'TextFileReader' object is not subscriptable

How I can introduce the chuncksize in test data ?

Comment: For the chunking issue - be sure to post the full traceback on any questions on stack overflow, since [they're extremely helpful in debugging your issue](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/). Check out the pandas docs on [iterating through files chunk by chunk](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk). You need to loop over `submission`.

Comment: For visualizing extremely large datasets you might want to check out packages that are intended for this purpose, such as [holoviews](https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Large_Data.html) or [datashader](https://datashader.org/). You can of course subset your data into chunks as you're suggesting and create a plot each time, just include the plot creation steps in the for loop that iterates through your chunks. Each one will not be representative of the whole dataset, but this might be useful for understanding samples.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for error:
pandas in `read_csv()`Function, add `chunksize = None` After the parameters but now you specified it, so the returned file type is `<class 'pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader'>`

to solve it use this loop and chunksize = 100 and see what is happening it will print many tables:

```
for chunk in seg:
    print(seg)
```

Comment: Hi @younes ait m'ha - welcome to stack overflow! Please note that the original post specifically mentions the large size of the data, and is trying to get information about how to work with chunked data. Given this, suggesting that they use `chunksize=None` could potentially crash their kernel, and using a chunksize of 100 will print 1500 times as many chunks as the OP's question suggested. This is important context to your answer and limits its usefulness. Make sure to add that context! :)

Comment: this loop print this "<pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader object at 0x000001F4F16334C8>"